# Custom layout update not shown for CMS page

Tags: layout, cms-pages, magento2.4.1

I've made a custom layout update file according to the instruction (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html) in 2.4.1, but the option is not displayed for a CMS page I'm creating. I'm expecting a `LegacyHomepage` option to appear.

Current theme: `[vendor]_legacy`

CMS page ID: `legacy-homepage`

Layout file location: `app/design/frontend/[vendor]/legacy/layout/cms_page_view_selectable_legacy-homepage_LegacyHomepage.xml`

I can't tell what's incorrectly set up. I'd appreciate if anyone can spot anything.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layout files location is wrong:

**Layout file  is location:** `app/design/frontend/[vendor]/legacy/layout/cms_page_view_selectable_legacy-homepage_LegacyHomepage.xml`

**It should be**

`app/design/frontend/[vendor]/legacy/Mage_Cms/layout/cms_page_view_selectable_legacy-homepage_LegacyHomepage.xml`

`app/design/frontend/[vendor]/legacy/layout` is not readable layout folder  at

Magento readable folder is `app/design/frontend/[vendor]/legacy/{Module_vendor}_{ModuleName}/layout`

Comment: Worked thanks! (`Magento_Cms`)